# Phase space and uncertainty

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, phase-space

In phase space every point represents both position and momentum. Isn't it against of Uncertainty principle?

Comment: Based on the tags here, I'm assuming your asking this in the context of classical mechanics, so why do you think the Uncertainty Principle is relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phase space is a concept usually used in the framework of Classical Mechanics. While at the quantum level one can't specify momentum and position at the same time due to the Uncertainty Principle, when dealing with classical systems no such issue arises.

Furthermore, the phase space might still be a useful concept even in Quantum Mechanics, as long as one considers states as being similar to probability functions defined on it. See, for example, the [Wigner quasiprobability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution). The issue will arise only if you want to consider a state of definite position and momentum, but as long as you don't do that, the concept of phase space might still be useful and not in contradiction with the Uncertainty Principle.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the Uncertainty Principle as a guarantee that there are no "points" in a phase-space diagram, but instead "regions" whose area is $\Delta x \Delta p \gtrsim \hbar$.  If it's convienient to measure masses, distances, and time intervals in kilograms, meters, and seconds, the area of phase space occupied by a particle's trajectory will be *enormously* larger than $\hbar \approx 10^{-34} \rm\,J\,s$, and the approximation of the "point" in phase space is useful.